# The issue of React Lifecycle in a Functional Component (Data undefined in the child component)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-functional-component, react-lifecycle

I ran into a problem when I try to call backend api from a parent component the call result is always null in the child component.
Here is my implementation:
The parent component:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const { loadFiData, fiData, year } = useContext(DashboardContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    let loading = true;
    
    if (loading) loadFiData();

    return () => (loading = false);
  }, [year]);

  return (
    <div className="mt-5">
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child Component:

```
const Chart1 = () => {
  const { fiData } = useContext(DashboardContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fiData) {
      console.log('there is a data');
    } else {
      console.log('there is no data');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <h1>Child</h1>
  );
};
```

so I look for a way to execute the function that calls the backend from the parent component first so the child can access to the data.

Comment: When you pass an empty array to `useEffect` it only runs on mount and unmount. Try putting your log statements outside of the `useEffect` method.

Comment: YEH bro that's the issue, cause the empty array is fired only one in the mount of the component but when adding a dependency it's like on updating, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `fiData` as a dependency of `useEffect` in `Chart1/Child` component. Then the code inside the useEffect should run 2 times. It should first console `there is no data` and when the request completes inside the context, then it should console `there is a data`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (fiData) {
        console.log('there is a data');
    } else {
        console.log('there is no data');
    }
}, [fiData]);
```